# GNU Radio--raw data from uhd_fft.py

Tags: python, gnuradio

I would like to do spectrum sensing with GNU radio.  Is there a good way to get the raw output from uhd_fft.py (the value for each frequency)?  I would like to do this programatically (with code), rather than through a GUI.

I have tried doing spectrum sensing with usrp_spectrum_sense.py, and this script has questionable accuracy and seems to be much slower than uhd_fft.py.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really direct your question to the GNURadio mailing list. This is a very application-specific question, which isn't necessarily appropriate for SO.

https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/discuss-gnuradio

To answer your question a bit, uhd_fft.py is just a Python program that is doing a transform on your data. You can do the same thing in C++ with GNURadio. Just edit the Python code to dump the bin data instead of plotting it and you should get what you want.